# Migrating Database from MySQL Workbench to SharePoint List for Python Flask Application

Tags: python, mysql, list, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

We are new to this site and request your kind support in solving our query.

We have a created python flask based web application wherein we have used MySQL WorkBench as a database.

Now, we have been requested to change the database from MySQL to SharePoint List.

We would like to know if we can connect to SharePoint List with Python code. If yes, how to change the code base to the minimum with regards to MySQL queries as we were informed that SharePoint List supports MsSQL queries.

Sincerely, Irfan M.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I think the biggest issue with your need is that a SharePoint List is certainly not a database or a database alternative. It is a common misconception to use them as databases for Power Applications or applications hosted on SharePoint, however, you cannot consider SharePoint Lists as a database.

That being said, they are pretty convenient to hold data as they offer a Rest API authenticated with OAUTH2 security, identity & versin management, ...

You will not have any language similar to SQL queries, however the API offers two alternatives:

- ODATA standard (filter, select, top, skip, expand) in your Rest calls
- CAML queries (XML that does about the same thing as the first)

Here is the documentation for you, there's potentially a lot of work ahead, depending on the complexity of your current scheme.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/working-with-lists-and-list-items-with-rest

And as a little bonus, please consider the very, very, very big limitations upon using SharePoint lists. You cannot have more than 5000 items in a list without a garanteed index as prime filter, you cannot query more than 2000 items without paging, ...

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/sharepoint-rest-api-limitation

Comment: would you please provide us with an update on the status of your issue?

Comment: I have no issue, could you please explain what you mean ?